# How to copy stored procedure from one database to another database on same server dynamically

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a script to copy a stored procedure to another database on the server:

```
SELECT @def = [definition] 
FROM [@from_db].sys.sql_modules 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyProcedure') 

EXEC(@def);
```

However this doesn't work, How can I copy a stored procedure from one database to another?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''
    ,@TargetDBName NVARCHAR(255) = 'TargetDBName'

DECLARE c CURSOR
FOR
SELECT DEFINITION
FROM SourceDBName.[sys].[procedures] p
INNER JOIN SourceDBName.sys.sql_modules m ON p.object_id = m.object_id

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT
FROM c
INTO @sql

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '''', '''''')
    SET @sql = 'USE [' + @TargetDBName + ']; EXEC(''' + @sql + ''')'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM c
    INTO @sql
END

CLOSE c

DEALLOCATE c
```